# Javamail Auto-reply for my domain

Tags: jakarta-mail

Javamail Auto-reply

I would truly like to auto-reply to an email using Javamail.

I already use my domain email to send a confirmation code during registration.

What I need now is when an email is sent to choices@mydomain.com I can auto-reply with a canned email based on parsing out and reading the received email. It would be nice to include the username in the reply.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Tell us more about your environment (web app, esktop app, technology, J2EE / AppEngine ?)

Answer (score 1):

This simplest approach is to write a program that monitors your mailbox and creates and sends a reply based on every message it sees.  The JavaMail download bundle includes a sample program monitor.java that will get you started.  The MimeMessage.reply method will be helpful.  You'll have to fill in the content of the reply message yourself.  Various other JavaMail sample programs will show you how to send a message once you've created it.

And don't forget to read the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Initially I wanted to run it from the web server as a web app with Java Mail on a linux server using Apache, Tomcat, and JDK 1.7. Now I think it would be more flexible to run a desktop app on a windows 7 machine that monitors lets say an online gmail account. It is important to be able to reply immediately upon receiving the email. Can this be done from a desktop app or will there be a delay? Thank you guys again.

Comment: A web app is normally only going to respond to web requests, so it's not the best match here.  You need a separate app or thread that's just going to watch the mailbox, without any other user requests.  A "desktop" or standalone app will work fine for this.  What sort of delay there might be between when a new message arrives and when your app will see it depends a lot on your mail server.  Oh, and I assume you'll be using IMAP to talk to your mail server for this; using POP3 presents another whole set of issues.

Comment: thank you guys for the nice reply, the javamail bundle is great. Had a couple more questions. I'm using a JDialog to get the password and pass the argument array with monitor.main(args); 1) the login dialog never goes away, and 2) what would be the call from my JMenuItem Exit to kill the folder.addMessageCountListener? Almost done :)

Comment: 1) I don't know, 2) folder.removeMessageCountListener

Comment: What is the best way to call monitor.main(args) so it doesn't freeze my program? I just found and will try java.util.concurrent. Thanks for addMessageCountListener :)

Answer (score 1):

Nice thinking John,I had the same problem in my project, in JSP and I solved it as shown below with java class as ReadingMail

```
package com;import java.io.*;import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
public class ReadingMail {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    try{
        String host = "pop.gmail.com";
        String user="username";
        String password="password";
    // Get system properties
   Properties properties = System.getProperties();

    // Get the default Session object.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);

    // Get a Store object that implements the specified protocol.
    Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");

    //Connect to the current host using the specified username and password.
    store.connect(host, user, password);

    //Create a Folder object corresponding to the given name.
    Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");

    // Open the Folder.
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    Message[] message = folder.getMessages();

    // Display message.
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("------------ Message " + (i + 1) + " ------------");

        System.out.println("SentDate : " + message[i].getSentDate());
        System.out.println("From : " + message[i].getFrom()[0]);
        System.out.println("Subject : " + message[i].getSubject());
        System.out.print("Message : ");

        InputStream stream = message[i].getInputStream();
        while (stream.available() != 0) {
            System.out.print((char) stream.read());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    folder.close(true);
    store.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
public String Manu()
{
    String email=null;
    try{
        String host = "pop.gmail.com";
 //        String user = "xyz";
 //        String password = "12345";
        String user="username@gmail.com";
        String password="password";
    // Get system properties
   Properties properties = System.getProperties();

    // Get the default Session object.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);

    // Get a Store object that implements the specified protocol.
    Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");

    //Connect to the current host using the specified username and password.
    store.connect(host, user, password);

    //Create a Folder object corresponding to the given name.
    Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");

    // Open the Folder.
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    Message[] message = folder.getMessages();




    // Display message.
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("------------ Message " + (i + 1) + " ------------");

       // System.out.println("SentDate : " + message[i].getSentDate());
        //System.out.println("From : " + message[i].getFrom()[0]);
        email=message[i].getFrom()[0]==null?null:((InternetAddress) message[i].getFrom()[0]).getAddress();
        System.out.println("From addrss is..........................."+email);
       // System.out.println("Subject : " + message[i].getSubject());
        System.out.print("Message : ");

        InputStream stream = message[i].getInputStream();
        while (stream.available() != 0) {
            System.out.print((char) stream.read());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    folder.close(true);
    store.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return email;
}
```

You can fetch the username from the database and provide it as message in this program.